# How to set up a Static IP for a Virtual Machine (CentOS)

Tags: networking, vmware, centos-7

I am using VMware 9 and my host system is windows 10 and guest VM is CentOs 7
i want to use a bridge connection and assign a static Ip to my guest vm(CentOs)
how it can be done. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the network type to "Bridged" in the VM manager, then inside the guest configure the network interface with your static IP either using command line tools (e.g. you can follow this [guide](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/configure-centos-6-network-settings/)) or using the Network Administration Tool (see this other [guide](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-network-config.html)).